# How to send mail from a scheduled task in shopware6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I am trying to send mail from the scheduled task using
MailService but in that, I need a sales channel Id how can I get that?

Can I send mail without the sales channel  Id? or Is there any other method to send mail

Here is my code:

**services.xml**

```
<service id="Plugin\Service\ScheduledTask\TaskHandler">
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Content\Mail\Service\MailService"/>
    <argument type="service" id="scheduled_task.repository" />
    <tag name="messenger.message_handler" />
</service>
```

**TaskHandler.php**

```
class TaskHandler extends ScheduledTaskHandler
{
    private AbstractMailService $mailService;

    public function __construct(AbstractMailService $mailService,EntityRepositoryInterface $scheduleTaskRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct($scheduleTaskRepository);
        $this->mailService = $mailService;
    }

    public static function getHandledMessages(): iterable
    {
        return [ Task::class ];
    }

    public function run(): void
    {
        $recipients = [
            'test@gmail.com' => 'test'
        ];
        $data = new DataBag();

        $data->set('recipients', $recipients);
        $data->set('senderName', 'RAJ');
        $data->set('subject', 'test');
        $data->set('contentPlain', 'test');
        $data->set('salesChannelId','');//TODO

        $this->mailService->send($data->all(), Context::createDefaultContext(), []);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should just fetch a sales channel id, even if you might not need sales channel specific data in your mail. In the service the id is used to fetch a sales channel entity and for getting the mail address of the sender from the config, as the config is sales channel specific. If you don't provide a sales channel id, you must provide the `senderEmail` yourself: `$data->set('senderEmail', 'sender@example.com');`.

The only way to avoid an exception being thrown without providing a sales channel id, if you absolutely must, is enabling the test mode: `$data->set('testMode', true);`

I think the only other side effect of this, as far as I can see, is the twig renderer being set to test mode, which makes it less strict in regards to faulty variables and such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `MailService` then you have to set the `salesChannelId`. Otherwise you will get an exception.

If you don't have to use any particular sales channel or have only one storefront sales channel then you can get it's ID and use it:

services.xml

```
<service id="Plugin\Service\ScheduledTask\TaskHandler">
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Content\Mail\Service\MailService"/>
    <argument type="service" id="scheduled_task.repository" />
    <argument type="service" id="sales_channel.repository"/>
    <tag name="messenger.message_handler" />
</service>
```

TaskHandler.php

```
class TaskHandler extends ScheduledTaskHandler
{
    private AbstractMailService $mailService;
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $salesChannelRepository;

    public function __construct(AbstractMailService $mailService, EntityRepositoryInterface $scheduleTaskRepository, EntityRepositoryInterface $salesChannelRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct($scheduleTaskRepository);
        $this->mailService = $mailService;
        $this->salesChannelRepository = $salesChannelRepository;
    }

    public static function getHandledMessages(): iterable
    {
        return [ Task::class ];
    }

    public function run(): void
    {
        $recipients = [
            'test@gmail.com' => 'test'
        ];
        $data = new DataBag();

        $data->set('recipients', $recipients);
        $data->set('senderName', 'RAJ');
        $data->set('subject', 'test');
        $data->set('contentPlain', 'test');
        $data->set('salesChannelId', $this->getSalesChannelId());
        $data->set('contentHtml','test');

        $this->mailService->send($data->all(), Context::createDefaultContext(), []);
    }

    private function getSalesChannelId(): string
    {
        $criteria = (new Criteria())
            ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('type.iconName', 'default-building-shop'));

        return $this->salesChannelRepository->searchIds($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->firstId();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set `contentHtml`. Otherwise you will get a violation error.

Comment: Technically this isn't quite correct as it is possible to send the mail without a sales channel id and avoiding the exception. You can set `testMode ` to `true` but you must also provide `senderMail` yourself in that case. As the name suggests this is however not encouraged for production environments and it is indeed better to fetch a sales channel id.